# Return the value of MYSQL query if it is not empty otherwise return an empty string

Tags: mysql

I'm running a query where I one of the values should be an empty if the result of a subquery is empty or the result of the actual subquery. Here is the working query:

```
SELECT 
      CONCAT(u.Apellido, ', ', u.Nombre) AS Nombre,
      u.Email AS Email,
      u.Usuario AS Usuario,
      u.Filizacion AS Filiacion,
      CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tLaboratorio AS l WHERE l.Responsable = '$id') > 0)  THEN (SELECT l.Nombre FROM tLaboratorio AS l WHERE l.Responsable = '$id') ELSE '' END AS Laboratorio
FROM tUsuarios AS u
WHERE u.keyid = '$id';
```

It is the CASE part of the query that I want to simplify. Basically if the column Responsable in tLaboratorio contains $id then it should return the column Nombre from tLaboratorio and otherwise it should return nothing. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think COALESCE is what you are looking for.

If there can be only one row matching your criteria, this simple query shoud do it:

```
SELECT 
      CONCAT(u.Apellido, ', ', u.Nombre) AS Nombre,
      u.Email AS Email,
      u.Usuario AS Usuario,
      u.Filizacion AS Filiacion,
      COALESCE(l.Nombre, '')
FROM tUsuarios AS u
LEFT JOIN tLaboratorio AS l ON l.Responsable = '$id'
WHERE u.keyid = '$id';
```

If there can be more rows, you can still use COALESCE and have your query inside of it.

```
COALESCE( SELECT ... , '')
```